# Phpmyadmin, cuando cambio el valor sql_mode al reiniciar se pierde y hay que volverlo a cargar

Tags: phpmyadmin, php8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Para evitar errores al procesar algunos fomularios con  la sentencia By Group con PHP 8.1
Cambio el valor de la variable sql_mode del phpmyadmin, queda funcionando perfectamente.
Pero al reiniciar la máquina el phpmyadmin vuelve a poner los valores originales y tener que volverlo a cambiar
No encuentro la manera de que guarde los cambios

El Sistema Operativo es Linux Mint 21

Comment: Dónde estás cambiando ese valor? Cualquier archivo de configuración que modifiques, compártelo como texto por favor (omitiendo contraseñas y eso)

Comment: En el Localhost/variables del phpmyadim, y en el sql_mode preciso que guarde esto NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION cosa que al reiniciar lo pierde

Comment: Agregue en la pregunta la foto donde hago el cambio

Answer (score 0):

Si es cierto que se reinicia la configuración, al reiniciarse el servidor la configuración queda por defecto. me ha pasado en muchas veces que he montado el servidor.

según lo que he leído en otros foros, se pueden convertir en opciones predeterminadas a como lo necesitamos.

[Pueden revisar esta documentación, me sirvió mucho](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/374492)